# Lower bound for combined Gamma functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, gamma-function

I am asking for your help with an exercise from my general physics I class. The exercise is about the Gamma function and reads in this way.

Let $b\in\mathbb{N}, b\ge 2$ and $a\in (0, 1)$. Prove that there exists an lower bound which does not depend on $a$ for
$$\frac{\Gamma((a+b)/2)}{\Gamma((b-a)/2)}\cdot \left(\frac{\Gamma(b/2)}{\Gamma(b)}\right)^{a/b},$$
i.e. that there exists a positive constant $c$, non depending on $a$, such that
$$\frac{\Gamma((a+b)/2)}{\Gamma((b-a)/2)}\cdot \left(\frac{\Gamma(b/2)}{\Gamma(b)}\right)^{a/b}\ge c.$$

Here $\Gamma$ is defined, for $Re(z)>0$, as
$$\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1} e^{-t} dt$$
(Note that here $a, b, a-b, a+b$ are all real and nonnegative numbers).

The only idea I have so far is to split $\int_0^\infty \dots = \int_0^1 \dots +\int_1^\infty \dots$.
This led me to a huge number of integrals which I do not know how to manage and, honestly, I do not think is the right way to prove the result.
Anyone could please help in proving this result?

Finally, just out of my curiosity, I would like to understand if one can get an upper bound, too (but this second thing is not important and this thing will not affect the acceptance of the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lower bound.** By Gautschi’s Inequality
[$(5.6.4)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.6.E4),
\begin{align*}
\frac{{\Gamma \big( {\frac{b}{2} + \frac{a}{2}} \big)}}{{\Gamma \big( {\frac{b}{2} - \frac{a}{2}} \big)}} & = \frac{{b - a}}{2}\frac{{\Gamma \big( {\frac{{b - a}}{2} + a} \big)}}{{\Gamma \big( {\frac{{b - a}}{2} + 1} \big)}} \ge \frac{{b - a}}{2}\left( {\frac{{b - a}}{2} + 1} \right)^{a - 1}  \\ & \ge \frac{b}{2}\left( {\frac{b}{2} + 1} \right)^{a - 1}  \ge \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{b}{2} + 1} \right)^a
\end{align*}
for any $b\ge 2$ and $0<a<1$. We also have
$$
\left( {\frac{{\Gamma (b/2)}}{{\Gamma (b)}}} \right)^{1/b}  = \left( {\sqrt \pi  \,2^{1 - b} \frac{1}{{\Gamma ((b + 1)/2)}}} \right)^{1/b}  \ge \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{1}{{\Gamma (b)}}} \right)^{1/b}  \ge \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{b}
$$
if $b\ge 2$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\frac{{\Gamma \big( {\frac{b}{2} + \frac{a}{2}} \big)}}{{\Gamma \big( {\frac{b}{2} - \frac{a}{2}} \big)}}\left( {\frac{{\Gamma (b/2)}}{{\Gamma (b)}}} \right)^{a/b} & \ge \frac{1}{2}\left( {\left( {\frac{b}{2} + 1} \right)\left( {\frac{{\Gamma (b/2)}}{{\Gamma (b)}}} \right)^{1/b} } \right)^a \\ & \ge \frac{1}{2}\left( {\left( {\frac{b}{2} + 1} \right)\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{b}} \right)^a  \ge \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{1}{4}} \right)^a  \ge \frac{1}{8}.
\end{align*}
**Upper bound.** The quantity is unbounded. Assume that $0<a<1$. By the asymptotics
[$(5.11.12)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E12),
\begin{align*}
\frac{{\Gamma \big( {\frac{b}{2} + \frac{a}{2}} \big)}}{{\Gamma \big( {\frac{b}{2} - \frac{a}{2}} \big)}} \sim \left( {\frac{b}{2}} \right)^a
\end{align*}
as $b\to+\infty$. By Stirling's formula
$$
\left( {\frac{{\Gamma (b/2)}}{{\Gamma (b)}}} \right)^{1/b}  \sim \sqrt {\frac{{\rm e}}{2}} \frac{1}{{b^{1/2} }}
$$
as $b\to+\infty$. Consequently,
$$
\frac{{\Gamma \big( {\frac{b}{2} + \frac{a}{2}} \big)}}{{\Gamma \big( {\frac{b}{2} - \frac{a}{2}} \big)}}\left( {\frac{{\Gamma (b/2)}}{{\Gamma (b)}}} \right)^{a/b} \sim \left( {\frac{{\rm e}}{8}} \right)^{a/2} b^{a/2} 
$$
as $b\to+\infty$.

Comment: Gary, thank you for your answer (+1). Any suggestion for the upper bound? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Physicsuser See my edit.

Comment: Thank you, @Gary!

Comment: there is a mistake in the second line. It is not true that $(b/2 +1)^{a-1} >(b/2 +1)^{a}$ for $0<a<1$.

Comment: That is not what I claim there. Note the extra factor $b$.