# Lower bound for $\left(\frac{\Gamma(a/2)}{\Gamma(a)}\right)^{1/a}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, gamma-function

Let $a\in\mathbb N, a\ge 2$. During calculus class, the lecturer said that
$$\left(\frac{\Gamma(a/2)}{\Gamma(a)}\right)^{1/a}\ge \frac{1}{2a},$$
where $\Gamma$ denotes the Gamma-function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function.

When I asked for a motivation, he simply replied that it easily comes from the properties of the Gamma function.

I am trying to use the property $\Gamma(a+1)= a\Gamma(a)$ trying to write that quotient in a smart way, but with any success so far.

Anyone could please help me with that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you see from the functional equation for the gamma function that if you multiply $\Gamma(a/2)$ by $a/2$ exactly $a$ times you will get something smaller than $\Gamma(a) $?

Comment: Did any of us answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

This is true but you can have much better bounds.

Take logarithms, use Stirling approximation to have
$$\log \left(\left(\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   (a)}\right)^{\frac{1}{a}}\right)=\frac{1}{2} (-\log (a)+1-\log (2))+\frac{\log (2)}{2 a}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^2}\right)$$

Exponentiate
$$\left(\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   (a)}\right)^{\frac{1}{a}}=\sqrt{\frac{e}{2a}} \left( 1+\frac{\log (2)}{2 a}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^2}\right)\right)$$

$$\left(\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   (a)}\right)^{\frac{1}{a}}>\sqrt{\frac{e}{2a}} \qquad \forall a >0$$

Comment: Claude Leibovici, thank you for your answer (+1). Also, could you please edit your answer explaining how can I get exactly that bound?

Comment: @C.Bishop. As I wrote, take logarithms and apply twice Stirling approximation. This gives the first result. Now, use Taylor remembering that $x=e^{\log(x)}$. That's all. Cheers :-)

Comment: This gives the lower bound for sufficiently large $a$ only.

Comment: @Gary, I have just found that you answer my question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4749494/lower-bound-for-combined-gamma-functions

Comment: @Gary could you please explain that step in more detail? I do not understand from where the $\sqrt{\pi} 2^{1-b}$ comes from and how you get the last two inequalities. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look up the Legendre duplication formula.

Comment: @Gary thanks, I got it. Where do the last two inequalities come from? Thanks.

Comment: I got the last one. It remains the second last (if you want).

Comment: Monotonicity of the gamma function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approximation,
not a strict bound,
for the more general form
$\left(\dfrac{\Gamma(ca)}{\Gamma(a)}\right)^{1/a}$
which agrees with
Claude Leibovici's bound.

For large $a$
and fixed $c > 0$,
(this problem is for
$c=\frac12$)

$\begin{array}\\
(\Gamma(a))^{1/a}
\approx \dfrac{a}{e}\\
\text{so}\\
(\Gamma(ca))^{1/(ca)}
&\approx \dfrac{ca}{e}\\
\text{so}\\
(\Gamma(ca))^{1/a}
&=((\Gamma(ca))^{1/(ca)})^{c}\\
&\approx (\dfrac{ca}{e})^{c}\\
\text{so}\\
\left(\dfrac{\Gamma(ca)}{\Gamma(a)}\right)^{1/a}
&=\dfrac{(\Gamma(ca))^{1/a}}{(\Gamma(a))^{1/a}}\\
&\approx\dfrac{(\dfrac{ca}{e})^{c}}{\dfrac{a}{e}}\\
&=c^c(\dfrac{a}{e})^{c-1}\\
&=c^c(\dfrac{e}{a})^{1-c}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a = 2b$ with $b \ge 1$ an integer. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{{\Gamma (b)}}{{\Gamma (2b)}} & = \frac{1}{{(2b - 1)(2b - 2) \cdots (b + 1)b}} \ge \frac{1}{{(2b)(2b) \cdots (2b)(2b)}} \\ & = \frac{1}{{(2b)^b }} \ge \frac{1}{{(2b)^{2b} }} \ge \frac{1}{{(2 \cdot 2b)^{2b} }}.
\end{align*}
Now let $a = 2b+1$ with $b \ge 2$ an integer. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{{\Gamma (b + 1/2)}}{{\Gamma (2b + 1)}} &\ge \frac{{\Gamma (b)}}{{\Gamma (2b + 1)}} = \frac{1}{{2b(2b - 1)(2b - 2) \cdots (b + 1)b}} \\ & \ge \frac{1}{{(2b + 1)(2b + 1) \cdots (2b + 1)(2b + 1)}}  = \frac{1}{{(2b + 1)^{b + 1} }} \\ &\ge \frac{1}{{(2b + 1)^{2b + 1} }} \ge \frac{1}{{(2 \cdot (2b + 1))^{2b + 1} }},
\end{align*}
where in the first step we used the monotonicity of the gamma function for $b\ge 2$. The case $b=3$ is easy to check by hand.